# How to send an email with EJB

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm new in Java EE, and for my project I need to send an email.  If anyone can put the steps and some code, I would be grateful!

Comment: Surely googling for "java email" returns some results.

Comment: If you're stuck, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried this, and I had a error : 
 Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.topnet.tn, port: 25, response: 421

Answer (score 2):

The following code works very well with Google SMTP server. You need to supply your Google username and password.

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class GoogleMail {
    private GoogleMail() {
    }

    /**
     * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
     *
     * @param username GMail username
     * @param password GMail password
     * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
     * @param title title of the message
     * @param message message to be sent
     * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
     * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
     */
    public static void Send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        GoogleMail.Send(username, password, recipientEmail, "", title, message);
    }

    /**
     * Send email using GMail SMTP server.
     *
     * @param username GMail username
     * @param password GMail password
     * @param recipientEmail TO recipient
     * @param ccEmail CC recipient. Can be empty if there is no CC recipient
     * @param title title of the message
     * @param message message to be sent
     * @throws AddressException if the email address parse failed
     * @throws MessagingException if the connection is dead or not in the connected state or if the message is not a MimeMessage
     */
    public static void Send(final String username, final String password, String recipientEmail, String ccEmail, String title, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        // Get a Properties object
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

        /*
        If set to false, the QUIT command is sent and the connection is immediately closed. If set 
        to true (the default), causes the transport to wait for the response to the QUIT command.

        ref :   http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html
                http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5205249
                smtpsend.java - demo program from javamail
        */
        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        // -- Create a new message --
        final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@gmail.com"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

        if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
        }

        msg.setSubject(title);
        msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

        t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());      
        t.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the m username and the password ?? in which line ?

Comment: Those are parameters that you pass when calling the method `Send()`.

Comment: I noticed that you are new to SO.  Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answers your question.

Comment: I got this error : Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.topnet.tn, port: 25, response: 421

Comment: In your command prompt, type `ping smtp.gmail.com` and press enter.  What is the output?

Comment: it's responding, 4 recieved 0 lost, so what's the problem ?

Comment: It's not saying that it timed out?

Comment: no, I think it's from the code !

Comment: The code works fine, it could just be an error with the server.

Comment: @syb0rg I am impressed with your dedication :)